# Python - How to not get exponent in scientific notation (e.g 1.2**1000 = 1.5179100891722457e+79)

Tags: python, scientific-notation

When calculating the following `2**1000` for example you get the whole value

> 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376

But if you do the same for a float i.e `1.2**1000` it gives

> 1.5179100891722457e+79

Is there a built-in way to get the whole value of such a calculation (Not in scientific notation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the behavior you're seeing is that the first expression results in an integer since both of its operands are integers, while the second expression is a floating point number because one of the operands is a float.  To get the result you want, you can cast the result of the second expression to an int:

```
>>> int(1.2**1000)
15179100891722457049849556131606991918673074938672571271083893226004713928916992L
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `format()`

```
    a = 1.2**1000
    print(format(a, 'f'))
```

Gives the output `15179100891722457049849556131606991918673074938672571271083893226004713928916992.000000`

Answer (score 1):

Try casting to an integer.

```
int(1.2 ** 1000)
```

If you want to get decimals though you'll need to do some additional work depending on your goal

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to print it

```
print("{:.3E}".format(1234567890987654321))
```

This will output:

```
1.235E+18
```

You can also have decimal values. It will format it similarly.

```
print("{0:.3E}".format(1234567890987654321.98765432))

1.235E+18
```

If you want to get the full number printed, then you can do the following:

```
y = 1234567890987654321.98765432
print(f"{y:.22}")
```

It will output:

```
1234567890987654400.0
```